# FormatDate definition

Tags: c#

I have DateTime property DateCreation, which is not null.
I can do this:

```
String test=myObject.DateCreation.FormatDate();
```

If DateTime propert on object is nullable, like this:

```
public virtual DateTime? LastInteractionDate { get; set; }
```

I can't do this:

```
String test=myObject.LastInteractionDate.FormatDate();
```

The error is:
 DateTime? does not contain a definition for 'FormatDate'

How to solve that to have empty string if null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `.Value` to get the underlying value type:

```
String test = myObject.LastInteractionDate.Value.FormatDate();
```

and to check against null:

```
String test = myObject.LastInteractionDate != null
    ? myObject.LastInteractionDate.Value.FormatDate()
    : string.Empty;
```

In this case if the `LastInteractionDate` property is null the result will be an empty string.

Comment: You can also use the `HasValue` property instead of `!= null`.

Comment: That's correct, `HasValue` is an alternative method for checking against null.

Comment: And if using C# 6 - `string test = myObject?.LastInteractionDate?.FormatDate();`

Comment: Thank you all, C# 6 syntax is interesting but can you add the value also for null? Something like:
`string test = myObject?.LastInteractionDate?.FormatDate():string.Empty;`

I thought that variable declaration is enough to get the type.
I didn't know about the trick with ".Value" for nulls.